# Multi-platform C++ project structure

Tags: c++, directory, structure, project

I actually need help on how to structure my project (the directory tree).
I plan to code a network library split in multiple parts (one for server, one for client etc)

I am actually coding on Windows but I plan to make it multi-platform in the future.

My current setup is:

```
Solution folder
    - doc           // Doxygen generated documentation
    - include       // Public headers
    - lib           // Output libraries
        - Debug
        - Release
    - source        // Private implementation and headers
    Doxyfile
    Solution.sln
```

My question is, where am I supposed to put the project files for each IDE ?
Visual Studio generates multiple files per project, I don't know where am I supposed to store them, as there might be another IDE that does it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include any of the files generated by the `IDE` in your project. Let each developer choose their own `IDE`. Just package the files relevant to the program/library itself when you distribute the source code and let each developer import it into their own preferred `IDE`.

You will have to choose some cross-platform way of building the progs/libs.

`Makefile` is pretty universal. Most `IDEs` can run a project from its `Makefile`. Or you can use one of many cross-platform build systems that generate a `Makefile`.

Also you may want to keep your sources under version control such as [git](https://github.com/).

Comment: My question was about what directory should contain the .vcxproj files. I never used Makefile yet, I don't even think VS supports it (it can only import one but it will still be vcxproj then). I thinked to making a build directory then a subfolder called msvc14, and the projects would be in there, is that a good setup ?

Comment: @Antony Unfortunately VS is not a multi-platform IDE. If you want your project to be multi-platform then you really need to use a multi-platform build system. That doesn't stop you from using VS and **also** distributing VS project files for those who happen to use VS. But people on other platforms will need something they can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a cross platform project, then simply use an IDE and programming language that is suitable for the task. You can for example just use Eclipse to get a C++ support and get an output for your project that can run on several operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

For each platform, different codeset will be executed and hence the will have separate code base for each platform otherwise it will not compile. The solution is to have separate file for platform specific functionality and tag that file for the platform, maintaining one codebase. To work on a platform, pull the platform specific required code from the repository.  Here is an example ["Upload XML data to MySQL or NoSQL"](http://oodupinc.blogspot.com/2016/11/defaulthandler-uploadfilestring-read.html)